# Generate 3 dimension dynamic array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I generate 3 dimension dynamic array in jquery, ( the length if the array should be dynamic and feed in from a variable )?

Comment: The same way you do it in javascript. The length of js arrays is dynamic according to elements in it

Comment: You don't do this "in jQuery". jQuery doesn't do this. jQuery does DOM manipulation. This is not DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jquery, just plain JS

```
   var threeDarr = [];

    var firstArr = [];
    var secondArr = ['x','y','z'];

    firstArr.push(secondArr);
    threeDarr.push(firstArr);



     console.log(threeDarr[0][0][0]); //prints x
     console.log(threeDarr[0][0]); // prints ["x", "y", "z"]
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDbBx/)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in javascript are dynamic by nature.

To add a dimension, simply put an array in the item you want to have the next dimension.

```
var 1D = [0, 0];

var 2D = [ 
    [0, 0], 
    [0, 0] 
];

var 3D = [ 
    [ 
        [0, 0], 
        [0 ,0], 
        [0, 0] 
    ], 
    [ 
        [0, 0], 
        [0 ,0], 
        [0, 0] 
    ], 
    [ 
        [0, 0], 
        [0 ,0], 
        [0, 0] 
    ]
];
```